# How to avoid TCP aggregation in 'C'?

Tags: c, tcp

I'm sending many TCP packets each of size 50 bytes over the network. Later I found it out TCP aggregates a few 50 byte packets into a single TCP packet. My question is, is there a way to avoid TCP aggregation in 'C' program?

Comment: Why do you want to?  Doesn't aggregation make your network work better?

Comment: I don't care about network performance. I would like to send each 50 bytes as a separate TCP packet over the network. I want to know how to do that.

Comment: You haven't answered the question. *Why* do you want to do that?

Comment: @EJP: The receiver doesn't want to have packets aggregated. It's their requirement not mine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Packing multiple sent packets into a single TCP packet is handled using an algorithm known as [Nagle's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm). To disable it, [set the `TCP_NODELAY` option on your socket](http://www.unixguide.net/network/socketfaq/2.16.shtml):

```
int flag = 1;
setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, &flag, sizeof(flag));
```

Note that this decreases the efficiency of your network, and should be avoided unless you really do need each packet to be sent immediately.

Comment: @user1960286 That still doesn't guarantee that individual sends will be received atomically, which is what you really seem to want.

Comment: @EJP: Then, what's the reliable way to do it?

Comment: Add framing to your data stream. (For instance, write the length of a frame preceding the data.)

Answer (score 3):

TCP fundamentally does not provide a packet-based service at the application layer.  Applications using TCP that need more than a pure stream must provide their own framing mechanism.

Whilst the `TCP_NODELAY` option will often cause each application-level write to be carried in a separate frame (unless it's larger than the MTU), there's no guarantee.  In particular, if the recieve window has been reduced to zero (common on a connection where you are sending bulk data), then multiple writes can still be coalesced when the receive window opens up again.

Furthermore, even if the sending TCP does not coalesce your writes, there is *no way* to stop the receiving side from presenting the data from multiple TCP frames in one application-level read from the socket - this will particularly occur when your receiving application is not scheduled for some time, or when packet loss occurs on the connection.

If your application assumes that each application-level write on the sending end will be paired exactly with an application-level read on the receiving end, you are setting yourself up for rare and hard-to-reproduce bugs.

Answer (score 1):

TCP does not, by definition, offer any packetization services.  TCP is a byte-stream oriented protocol.  The best you can do is to insert your own framing marks into your data.  Then if your receiver can at least detect bad frames (aggregated data perhaps) and drop such data, that sort of gets you where you want to be.

The send-as-soon-as-possible approach (ala NODELAY) is not guaranteed to work because your receiver can still aggregate the data.  This is more probable if any tcp data gets delayed for whatever reason

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the TCP_NODELAY flags in the send call. However it depends on the TCP stack if this is supported or not.

Comment: I'm not aware of any TCP/IP implementations that don't support it. Are you?